# How to define a global onkeydown for all frames of a page?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, frames

I have a pretty complex legacy multi-frame page that must be IE-11 compatible and that needs to respond to hotkeys events.

Unfortunately, I've noticed that I can't just declare a JS method in the parent page. Instead, it seems that each frame needs its own document.onkeydown() method because right now, the events work only when I click on the frames that have the method onkeydown() defined.

Is there any way to globally define this method so all frames will deal with the event? I am trying to avoid the uncomfortable situation where I have to declare the same method (or the same JS code) for each page (and it will be a nightmare because the frames are dynamically generated pages routed by some struts/spring mvc rules)

Comment: You _could_ put that code in a reusable file :)

Comment: Alternatively, whenever a hot key is detected in the parent frame, you send a PostMessage to the nested iframes, which will then invoke their internal functions that you want to be triggered by the same hot key.

Comment: @Strelok of course. But I would need to add a reference to it on all the pages that possibly may be called by the frames?

Comment: @Terry I don't think it works this way. If the onkeydown is defined in the master page, it is not recognized when you click on any of the inner frames. The situation I want to avoid it to touch all the inner frame pages (which are as many as 40, 60)

Comment: I didn’t say you have to remove the key down bindings in the child pages. What I’m proposing is a way for the parent frame to inform the child frame of the event, if the child frame is not in focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can interpret this question in two ways, and I think both/either could be useful so I'm going to answer both.

**1) How can I share code (a function/method/class whatever*) between multiple HTML frames?**

There isn't really a proper way to do this within the browser, at least not how I think you want. Frames, being considered a legacy feature, haven't changed much since the 90's and that was before large complex JS codebases were a thing.  There isn't a native way to define a function 'globally' without considering something like a browser extension.

This isn't usually a problem because typical way to do this would be for each frame to be drawing from a common script. You would put your script tag at the top (or bottom) of the HTML page.

```
<script src='common-code.js'></script>
```

But if you are asking, how can I have this JS function existing in every frame without me updating each frame's seperate HTML? Then I fear you're out of luck. It's a feature of how each frame is considered a seperate document, and for security reasons you can't reach into another document and say 'run this code'.

I would try and find a way to bulk update the pages and add a script tag that includes or fetches the common code, or you may be in luck if some common HTML has already been defined you can add it there.

<sub>* Surprise, in JavaScript all of these are the same thing really!</sub>

**2) How can I pass an event (keydown) from one frame to another?**

You would emulate this using the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method of `Window` to send a message from the one frame to another the recipient frame would then handle the message, rather than the native event.

Whether you are using a frameset or iframes I believe you would have to pass each event up to the parent, which would then send the event back down by using the [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames) list. Bit of a headache but possible.

(To be clear this doesn't get around the limitation discussed in the first answer. This is how you would achieve a situation where a click in one frame gets 'handled' by another - you would still have to update both frames to include the message passing and handling code).